# Javascript: textContent and getElementByTagName arent working in my code

Tags: javascript, html

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> sample </title>
<script>

var para = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0]; // First <p> in the document
var text = para.textContent; // Text is "This is a simple document."
para.textContent = "Hello World!"; // Alter paragraph content

</script>

</head>
<body>
<p> This is a simple document. </p>
</body>
</html>
```

According to the book i am using to study javascript, this should change the text inside the

tag to "Hello World!" but i dont understand why it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your code trying to access not yet rendered element. In order to fix this problem you can use following code:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var para = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0]; // First <p> in the document
    var text = para.textContent; // Text is "This is a simple document."
    para.textContent = "Hello World!"; // Alter paragraph content
}, false);
```

[Link to fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/hxdjbq11/2/)

So in this code we are attaching event listener for windows load event. Upon load of window completed (all elements rendered by browser) this event will be fired.

Comment: I should have thought of that earlier. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The script is running before any `p` elements exist on the page. You should move the script to just before `</body>`.

As an aside: other answers are suggesting binding to the `load` event. The `load` event triggers after all images, external resources, and iframes are loaded as well, which really isn't necessary for this example. The `readystatechange` or `domcontentloaded` events would be more appropriate (equivalent to jQuery's `ready` event) which fires when the DOM has finished loading and before `load` would fire. Just moving the script to the bottom of the page would have the exact same effect without introducing more code, and it would run sooner.

Answer (score 0):

As @Cory said, you are running the script before the html. Another option is put the code inside  `window.onload` function:

```
 window.onload=function(){

     //your code

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option to Cory's solution is to put your code in a `window.onload` function. Like this:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function(){
        var para = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0]; // First <p> in the document
        var text = para.textContent; // Text is "This is a simple document."
        para.textContent = "Hello World!"; // Alter paragraph content
    };
</script>
```

That way the code will only run after the page has loaded.

You could also put your code into a custom function and add an `onload` event handler to your body tag that calls the function:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> sample </title>
<script>
    function changePara(){
        var para = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0]; // First <p> in the document
        var text = para.textContent; // Text is "This is a simple document."
        para.textContent = "Hello World!"; // Alter paragraph content
    };
</script>
</head>
<body onload="changePara();">
    <p> This is a simple document. </p>
</body>
```

I would personally recommend using `window.onload` because you could put your function into a javascript file and easily use and update it across your site.

Comment: I prefer window.onload as well. Thanks!